# How to know if the item of a TabControl is a listbox?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, listbox, tabcontrol, listboxitem

I was thinking on something like:

```
If TabControl1.Controls.Item(1) = ListBox Then

End If
```

Anyway to get if the item is a ListBox or a Button or something like that ?

Comment: Direct descendant controls of `TabControl` are `TabPages`.
For controls inside `TabPages` use something like this: `If TypeOf (TabControl1.TabPages(0).Controls(0)) Is ListBox Then....`

Comment: Assume you have 10 TabPages, each containing 10 Controls, are you going to add 100 `If` conditions (or one condition per type of Control)? Can you explain what are you trying to do instead of how you're trying to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious ways can test the class of an Object.

If you want to know if the object is literally a `ListBox`, and nothing else, you can do:

```
If myObject.GetType() = GetType(ListBox) Then
```

If you want to know if the object is a `ListBox` or is inheriting from `ListBox` at some point (I often use this form since a lot of the controls I use at work are wrapped into proprietary class):

```
If TypeOf myObject Is ListBox Then
```

There's not a "better method" between the two, it depends on what you're doing and what you need to know.

Now, in your specific case, there's something important that G3nt_M3caj pointed out: all the controls in the `TabControl1.Controls` collection will be of the `TabPage` class. You probably want to test a control from a specific `TabPage`, so you'll have to find it through your stuff, making sure that you don't create instability with nullPointerExceptions or the like. I gave you the mean to test your objects, but you'll still have to apply these tools to your current situation (which I have not enough info about to help much).

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Thanks for letting me know, I hadn't though about the specifics of testing TabControl's control list.